# Why are the outputs of `DataOutputStream` and `ObjectOutputStream` on same data different?

Tags: java

I am trying to compare the outputs of `DataOutputStream` and `ObjectOutputStream` on same data to be output:

```
Random random = new Random();
int[] numbers = new int[100];
for (int i=0; i<100; i++){
    numbers[i] = random.nextInt();
}

System.out.println("Output");
try(FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream("Object.txt");
    ObjectOutputStream oout = new ObjectOutputStream(fout)){
    oout.writeObject(numbers);
} catch (IOException e){
    System.err.println(e);
}

System.out.println("Output");
try(FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream("Data.txt");
    DataOutputStream dout = new DataOutputStream(fout)){
    for (int i=0; i<100; i++){
        dout.writeInt(numbers[i]);
    }
} catch (IOException e){
    System.err.println(e);
}
```

Why do the files they created differ?

```
$ diff Data.txt Object.txt 
Binary files Data.txt and Object.txt differ
```

Don't both output streams write the data in binary? Doesn't that mean their output should be the same?

Thanks.

Comment: ObjectOutputStream `writeObject` writes not data, but serialized version of object, which can be restored back to object by reading ObjectInputStream. And serialized version is not only data in the object... It is much better to read some basic Java documentation first :-)

Comment: Thanks. "serialized version is not only data in the object" I thought they were. What are some good readings?

Comment: It is just standard JavaDoc API about Serializable Interface and writeObject methods, But... do you really need to know that deep details? just look at file produced by writeObject. I guess it will be enough. Also in most cases you will never need to use writeObject/readObject. There are restrictions - object must implement Serializable interface, it must be same or higher JDK/JRE version when you write and read object... If you write object under Java 8 you will not be able read it under Java 7 ... etc. Keep the needed data instead of serialized object is much better.

Comment: Thanks. "Keep the needed data instead of serialized object is much better." What does "Keep the needed data" mean?

Comment: In your example - you need to keep your actual numbers, not a Java object which holds them in your particular program. So later I can write my program to use those numbers, and not necessary in Java but in any language I'd like to use.

Comment: Actually you just hit fundamental conception from where all data formats came - databases, XML, json, HTML and so on....

Answer (score 2):

ObjectOutputStream write serializable java object.
So if you read with ObjectInputputStream, it will give you java object.

DataOutputStream write bytes and DataInputputStream read bytes.

Ex)

```
class MyClass implements Serializable {
    String myData = "Hello?";
    int myInt = 12345;
    long myLong = 12412412412L;
}
```

Here is a serializable class.

```
try {

        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("datafile"));

        MyClass myClass = new MyClass();

        oos.writeObject(myClass);

        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("datafile"));

        MyClass read = (MyClass) ois.readObject();

    } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

With ObejectOutputStream, ObjectInputStream you can write and read java "Serializable" class object.

DataOutputStream, DataInputStream can write and read java primitive value (int, boolean, char, double, float, short)

So if you want write java class object use ObjectOutputStream, or just write primitive values use DataOutputStream.

Comment: Thanks. (1) Can serialization be done only by `ObjectOutputStream.writeObject`? Not by any method of any other IO stream class? (2) Could you simulate what `ObjectOutputStream.writeObject()` does in terms of `DataOutputStream`'s methods? So I can better understand their differences.

Comment: The main distinction is that DataOutputStream lets you write primitive Java data types, while ObjectOutputStream can also write graphs of Java objects.